# Mapping a circle to a point on a sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to come up with an explicit homotopy for a circular loop about the equator of a sphere and the constant loop (1, 0, 0). The stereo graphic projection was used for this problem elsewhere on stack exchange though I don't know how to form a homotopy from that projection. I don't know if it would be easier or not but, intuitively, I think that a homotopy map that rotates the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ to $y^2+z^2=1$ and then contracts the rotated circle to the point (1, 0, 0) would work although I'm not sure how to parametrize this homotopy. I do at least know that the circular loop can be parametrized as $(cos(2\pi s), sin(2\pi s), 0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation is a linear transformation, and is thus given by a matrix.  Since $(1,0,0) \mapsto (0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0) \mapsto (0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1) \mapsto (-1,0,0)$, the matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
To contract the circle down, use the straight line homotopy in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then divide by the magnitude to place it on the sphere.